# -std=c11 does not define _ISO11_SOURCE

Tags: c, macros, standards

Manual page for `feature_test_macros(7)` states:

> _ISOC11_SOURCE (since glibc 2.16)
> Exposes declarations consistent with the ISO C11 standard.  Defining this macro also enables C99 and C95 features (like _ISOC99_SOURCE).

```
Invoking the C compiler with the option -std=c11 produces the same effects as defining this macro.
```

At the same time `gcc(1)` specification for `-std=` doesn't mention macros anywhere.

Eventually, when the preprocessor stage is run, no standard-specific macros are defined, so, as I understand it, all standard libraries must reject declaring any function or variable inside them, as these declarations could vary depending on the standard used.

I've compiled(`gcc -std=c11 test.c`) and run this code, and it doesn't produce anything.

`test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
#ifdef _POSIX_SOURCE
  printf("_POSIX_SOURCE defined\n");
#endif  
  
#ifdef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
  printf("_POSIX_C_SOURCE defined: %jdL\n", _POSIX_C_SOURCE);
#endif

#ifdef _ISOC99_SOURCE
  printf("_ISOC99_SOURCE defined\n");
#endif

#ifdef _ISOC11_SOURCE
  printf("_ISOC11_SOURCE defined\n");
#endif

#ifdef _XOPEN_SOURCE
  printf("_XOPEN_SOURCE defined\n");
#endif
  

#ifdef _BSD_SOURCE
  printf("_BSD_SOURCE defined\n");
#endif

#ifdef _SVID_SOURCE
  printf("_SVID_SOURCE defined\n");
#endif

#ifdef _DEFAULT_SOURCE
  printf("_DEFAULT_SOURCE defined\n");
#endif

#ifdef _ATFILE_SOURCE
  printf("_ATFILE_SOURCE defined\n");
#endif

#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
  printf("_GNU_SOURCE defined\n");
#endif


  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

`gcc` version is (Debian 10.3.0-9) 10.3.0

`glibc` version is 2.31-17

So, do I miss something? Does it work in a different way?

Comment: I do not think “produces the same effects as defining this macro” means using `-std=c11` defines that macro; I think it means that some macro will be defined in such a way as to get the same effects from the library headers. That could be the fact that `-std=c11` sets `__STDC_VERSION__` to a suitable value, or it could be some other macro.

Comment: So, if some user-written library depends on `_ISOC11_SOURCE` macro for example, the statement from `feature_test_macros(7)` about equality of using `std=c11` and defining according macro is *false*. For me, these "effects" are not obvious. I think it would be better if these "effects" were enumerated clearly.

Comment: Per the [`feature_test_macros` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), “Feature test macros allow the programmer to control the definitions that are exposed by system header files when a program is compiled.” The man page tells you that **if** you define the feature test macros, **then** the system header files will respond in a certain way. It also tells you that **if** you use `-std=c11`, **then** the system header files will respond in a certain way…

Comment: … They do not tell you that if you use `-std=c11`, the macros will be defined in any particular way usable in user-written files.

Comment: _You_ must define `_ISOC11_SOURCE` -- it will _not_ be defined for you. Look at `features.h`. From that: _These are defined by the user (or the compiler) to specify the desired environment:_ `_ISOC11_SOURCE _POSIX_SOURCE _XOPEN_SOURCE _LARGEFILE_SOURCE _GNU_SOURCE _DEFAULT_SOURCE` These are the "top level" defines. If you did (e.g.) `#define _GNU_SOURCE #include <features.h>`, then you _could_ test the feature specific macros (e.g.): `#ifdef __USE_ISOC11` and it would be defined. When you define a top level, it _must_ appear before _any_ `#include` directives to be effective